# how to assign table styles with code to a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-style

I'm creating  a word document with data from  a Visual Basic 2010 software I created for my work, which consist in a report ... i was ask to generate a Microsoft word document, so now I'm creating a table and filling that table with data, something likes this

```
oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, 8, 4)
oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
oTable.Range.Font.Size = 10

oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Italic = True
oTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Datos de Facturación:"
oTable.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "            Enviar a:"
oTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = rs.Text
oTable.Cell(2, 1).Width = 75
oTable.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = dirfa.Text
oTable.Cell(3, 1).Width = 75 ..... etc..
```

Microsoft Word has some table designs styles like "DARK LIST - ACCENT 5". "DARK LIST - ACCENT 6" etc, I couldn't figure out how to set this styles to the table, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a style, you can use a document object:

```
Set doc = wd.Documents.Add(NewTemplate:=True)

With doc.Styles("Certificate")
    With .Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
        .Italic = True
        .Bold = True
    End With

    With .ParagraphFormat
        ''wdAlignParagraphCenter = 1
        .Alignment = 1
        .SpaceAfter = 0
        .SpaceBefore = 0
    End With
End With
```

Assign the style:

```
Set r = doc.Shapes("Course1").TextFrame.TextRange
r.Style = "Certificate"
```

For this particular case, you might use:

```
    oTable.Range.Style = "ANewStyle"
```

Or if built-in styles are available to you:

```
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Style = WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
```

Comment: Does not answer the question, which is how to reference the built in table styles?