# Apply table style to header using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-style

I'm writing VBA code in Word to format a table.  I need to allow the user to format the table header independently of the table body.  To do this I hoped to be able to use the built in table styles, however, when I do this the style is applied to the whole table and not just the header or body.

Below is the code that I'm using to apply a style to the header:

```
Sub FormatTableHeader(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)
Dim tbl As Table

If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)

    tbl.Rows(1).Range.Style = "TableHeader"
End If

End Sub
```

I also need to do something similar for the table body.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do using the table styles?  I know I could write code to format the table header, but I hoped to keep the code linked to the styles.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible but you could follow this [procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526778/how-to-assign-table-styles-with-code-to-a-word-document) to create your own styles and apply them on the header row or the table body.

```
Sub tableFormat()
Dim lastRow As Integer

lastRow = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count


With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Range.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
        .Italic = True
        .Bold = True
End With

For i = 2 To lastRow
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(i).Range.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 8
        .Italic = False
        .Bold = False
End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks - I saw this code too.  I've no problem creating the styles, it is just applying the style to just the header or just the body

Comment: thanks...but is this code to format a table in Excel?  I'm working in Word